# Symfony validation groups (not forms)

Tags: validation, symfony

Can't seem to get validation groups working. It works for the default group, however I cant seem to figure out how to specify different validation groups in the following:

```
$errors = $validator->validate($entity);
```

I've a simple entity I'm testing with:

```
/**
 * Class Login
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 */
class Login
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     message="not.blank",
     *     groups={"Default", "login"}
     * )
     *
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     message="email",
     *     groups={"Default", "login"}
     * )
     */
    public $email;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     message="not.blank",
     *     groups={"Default", "login"}
     * )
     */
    public $password;
}
```

If I add a parameter like this it complains:

```
$errors = $validator->validate($entity, 'login');
```

But there's got to be a way to do this, right?

Comment: I think you need to define your validation groups in the security.yml or validation.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the correct way of using Symfony3 validation groups is to list them as an array:

```
$errors = $validator->validate($entity, null, ['login']);
```

Btw, depending on your use case you might not need to set `Default` group for each property and use just group `Login` instead of `login`. Then when you validate the entity with group `Default` it'll automatically include assertions with group name equal to the class name which is `Login` in your case. For more details see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the Symfony code I found the following:

File:
/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/ValidatorInterface.php

Line:
public function validate($value, $constraints = null, $groups = null);

So if I change this:

```
$errors = $validator->validate($entity, 'login');
```

To this:

```
$errors = $validator->validate($entity, null, 'login');
```

It works!